# What is the adverbial pronoun doing in "J'en ai connu"

Tags: pronoms, adverbes, en

I recently heard somebody say "J'en ai connu", however, I'm slightly confused by the use of the pronoun `en`. According to my dictionary `connaître` only seems to be used with "de" when meaning "to know by" (e.g. Je le connais de nom - *I know him by name*), but I can't think how that would work in this case and it doesn't appear that "en" is replacing a partitive article. So why is "en" being used and what precisely does this phrase mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*J'en ai connu* means "I knew some of them/these" but without context, we cannot guess what *en* is referring to, it might be people, events, animals, things, whatever.

Note that normally, *connu* doesn't agree with the antecedent, e.g.:

> *Des situations imprévues, j'en ai connu.* not *…, j'en ai connues.*

However, once in a while agreement is done by some authors. See the [oqlf](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1037).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't hear the context, so I couldn't say either, but from your answer I can assume the "en" is being used to replace a quantity of something that the person was familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

`en` is commonly called `pronom neutre` and serves to ease up the weight of a sentence and to avoid repetition.

> - Est-ce que t'as eu des problèmes ?
> - Oui j'en ai eu.

It is also defined as being `partitif`, meaning it serves to indicate that you're talking about a part of a whole (quelques problèmes, de l'ensemble des problèmes) without having to specify wich.

In your example, you were talking about a specific person.

> -Je le connais de nom.

Imagine however, you were asked if you ever knew people only by name.

> -Connais-tu des gens que de nom ?
>   -Oui, j'en connais.

From all the people that could be known only by name, you know some.

Comment: "*Connais-tu des gens que de nom ?*" is dubious. I would use "*Connais-tu des gens uniquement de nom ?*"

Comment: Although my phrasing is syntactically correct and semantically clear, it does feel quite heavier on the tongue than yours. However, since it isn't erroneous I will leave the answer unchanged and point out that if ever the need to ask that question arises, I would recommend your version [ :